# Menu in Joomla site appears behind content

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla

I was asked to update a Joomla site from 1.5 to 2.5. In order to do so I had to update the site to 1.5.26 in order to use Jupgrade.

But upgrading the site to 1.5.26 something went wrong with the menu. It appears behind the content. I tried to use z-index in the many css the template has to resolve the problem but nothing seems to work. My CSS knowledge appears not to be enough to crack the nut.

The strangest thing for me is that the problem is with Chrome and FF, in IE it works allright (normally...)

Any advise would be really appreciated, it is a live site.

edit: deleted client side address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix adding the following to your CSS should work:

```
#horiz-menu li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Long term you should probably fix the root of the issue (likely some JavaScript by the looks of things).

It appears the opacity is set from 0 to 1 which is fine - the problem is once it reaches 1 it then transitions back to 0 again ... I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, but this is why the menu appears briefly then dissapears.

This should also act as a lesson never to upgrade CMSes live - **always** test locally, then upload, upgrading often seems to break things. It's never fun to have to fix something like this on a live site.

**EDIT:** Incidentally, you should probably tag this question for JavaScript too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked!

Agreed, I never thought such a small update will mess things up.